# Python sort_insertion function not working as I want it to work

Tags: python, insertion-sort

I need to make this sort-insertion algorithm for uni and I'm having trouble finding out why running this code gives "None".

I would want it to give me an output in this form:

```
[Product(name='banana', price=3.99), Product(name='peanut butter', price=4.2), Product(name='jelly', price=5.99), Product(name='Phoebe Bridgers CD', price=8.2), Product(name='guitar strings', price=12)]
```

My code:

```
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass


# dataclasses are a convenient new way to create simple "structs" or "records"
# in Python.
@dataclass
class Product:
    name: str
    price: float


# hint: lst is a python list, so use lst[i] to access element i
# (=what we called "get" in class), and use len(lst) to get its size.

# insertion sort


def sort_insertion(lst: List[Product]) -> List[Product]:
    """Sort lst by insertion, in-place."""


    # We start from 1 since the first element is already sorted as it is.
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        cur_value = lst[i].price
        cur_pos = i - 1

        while cur_pos >= 0 and cur_value < lst[cur_pos].price:
            lst[cur_pos + 1].price = lst[cur_pos].price
            cur_pos -= 1

        lst[cur_pos + 1].price = cur_value

sample_inventory = [
        Product(name="banana", price=5.99),
        Product(name="peanut butter", price=8.20),
        Product(name="jelly", price=3.99),
        Product(name="Phoebe Bridgers CD", price=12),
        Product(name="guitar strings", price=4.20),
    ]

print(sort_insertion(sample_inventory))
```

Comment: Your `sort_insertion()` method doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: Thanks!! That resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.  There were three problems: 1. In the first line in the while loop, you need to do a swap, as shown below. 2. you want to swap the whole product, not just its price. You do not want the price of the bananas and other items to change in the process of sorting. 3. This is an in_place sort, so you cannot say print(sort_insertion(sample_inventory)) since the function doesn't return anything.

```
def sort_insertion(lst: List[Product]) -> List[Product]:
    """Sort lst by insertion, in-place."""
    # We start from 1 since the first element is already sorted as it is.
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        cur_value = lst[i].price
        cur_pos = i - 1

        while cur_pos >= 0 and cur_value < lst[cur_pos].price:
            lst[cur_pos + 1], lst[cur_pos] = lst[cur_pos], lst[cur_pos + 1]
            cur_pos -= 1

        lst[cur_pos + 1].price = cur_value

sample_inventory = [
        Product(name="banana", price=5.99),
        Product(name="peanut butter", price=8.20),
        Product(name="jelly", price=3.99),
        Product(name="Phoebe Bridgers CD", price=12),
        Product(name="guitar strings", price=4.20),
    ]

sort_insertion(sample_inventory)
print(sample_inventory)

#output:
[Product(name='jelly', price=3.99), Product(name='guitar strings', price=4.2), Product(name='banana', price=5.99), Product(name='peanut butter', price=8.2), Product(name='Phoebe Bridgers CD', price=12)]
```